# Pop Up Blocker in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, window.open, popup-blocker

Below is the piece of code I am using to open a link in a new window say "abc".

If the user again clicks on the same link, it should close and reopen the link in the same window "abc".

```
window.openOrFocus = function(url, "abc") {
if (!window.popups) {
    window.popups = {};}
if (window.popups["abc"]){
   var v=window.open("", "abc");
    v.close();}
window.popups["abc"] = window.open(url, "abc");
}
```

But Now, say I click on the link, it opens the URL in a new window named "abc".
Now I go and close the window "abc". and go back and again click on the link.

That time it shows up the pop up blocker.

I am confused as to why this pop up blocker is coming when the I go and manually close the window and try to reopen by clicking on the link.

Happens both in IE as well as Chrome

Comment: You can use any bracing and indentation style you like in your own code, of course, but when asking for help, please use something *vaguely* standard. Hiding the closing `}` at the end of the last line of a block is extremely error-prone and hard to read, making it difficult for people to help you. (I **strongly** recommend switching to a normal style even when not asking for help.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're calling `window.open` with a blank URL or repeatedly in that case.

You don't need your `window.open("", "abc")` call; instead, just use the window reference you already have:

```
window.openOrFocus = function(url, windowName) {
    if (!window.popups) {
        window.popups = {};
    }
    if (window.popups[windowName]){
       window.popups[windowName].close();
    }
    window.popups[windowName] = window.open(url, windowName);
};
```

I would also listen for the `unload` event so you can remove your reference:

```
window.openOrFocus = function(url, windowName) {
    if (!window.popups) {
        window.popups = {};
    }
    if (window.popups[windowName]){
       window.popups[windowName].close();
    }
    window.popups[windowName] = window.open(url, windowName);
    window.popups[windowName].onunload = function() {
        delete window.popups[windowName];
    };
};
```

---

Side note: This is a syntax error:

```
window.openOrFocus = function(url, "abc") {
// --------------------------------^
```

I've replaced it with `windowName` in the code above.

Comment: Ya you are correct that I dont need to use 'window.open("","windowabc").
I had tried previously  with window.popup[name].close. Using this helps me to avoid the pop up issue but it is inconsistent on IE. Sometimes , it closes the window and sometimes it just ignores...

Comment: @VipulKumar: That's probably because you weren't tracking `unload`s.

Comment: I tried adding unload event also..but in IE, window.popups[windowname].close does not close the related window.
But here is the strange part...Second time I click the link the same code closes the link and reopens in IE. Third Time I click, it does not close the link..Fourth time I click..it closes !!!  I dont know why is this happening...